# connect ECONNREFUSED in Postman

Tags: c#, rest, postman

I am trying to test my REST API through postman and I am getting the following error:

[image]

This is my first REST API that I have written and I am very new to postman so not sure what am I doing wrong. Below is my code that I am trying to call in postman with this URL. I am passing two date parameters in the URL

```
https://localhost:44360/api/RecLoadPrime/insertRecLoadData/?RecStartDate=01/01/2020&RecEndDate=01/02/2020
```

Below is the code:

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using RecLoad.DAL;
    
    namespace RecLoad.Controllers
    {
        [Route("api/[controller]")]
        [ApiController]
        public class RecLoadPrimeController : ControllerBase
        {
            
            [Route("RecLoadPrime/insertRecLoadData/{RecStartDate}/{RecEndDate}")]
            [HttpPost]
            public void insertRecLoadData(string RecStartDate, string RecEndDate)
            {
                RecLoadDataProvider dataProvider = new RecLoadDataProvider();
                dataProvider.InsertData(RecStartDate, RecEndDate);
            }
        }
    }
```

There is nothing under the other tabs, Authorization, Headers, Body, PreRequest scripts, Test and  settings of postman. Below is the screen shot from postman:

[image]

When I trying to run the API directly by putting this URL in the browser, I am getting the error saying:

> This localhost page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:44360/api/RecLoadPrime/insertRecLoadData/?RecStartDate=01/01/2020&RecEndDate=01/02/2020

Comment: any help on this.

Comment: Tried Url encoding the slashes in date values? Also if route doesn't match you should be getting 404 not found, not connection refused error. Can you reach other endpoints in the same app?

Comment: you mean like this: https://localhost:44360/api/RecLoadPrime/insertRecLoadData/?RecStartDate=01//01//2020&RecEndDate=01//02//2020   OR like this: https://localhost:44360/api/RecLoadPrime/insertRecLoadData/?RecStartDate='01/01/2020'&RecEndDate='01/02/20

Comment: Like this : `https://localhost:44360/api/RecLoadPrime/insertRecLoadData/?RecStartDate=01%2F01%2F2020&RecEndDate=01%2F02%2F2020`

Comment: Now, I am getting an error saying: Error: unable to verify the first certificate

Comment: This is a brand new app. This is the first time, I wrote API so there are no other endpoints.

Comment: You must have enabled SSL, I can also see that from your URL. You can disable that for local dev.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210088/discussion-between-ram-kumaran-and-anjali).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was getting the same error. This solved my issue:

File -> Settings -> Proxy, then unmark "Use the system proxy"

Notice that I'm using Postman only for development (localhost), so I disabled the proxy.

Comment: Didn't solve my issue - still getting `ECONNREFUSED`.

Answer (score 3):

make sure the localhost server is still running when you send the request

Comment: Indeed, that was my case ahah.

Answer (score 2):

I was also getting the same error. This solved my issue :

I have unchecked the Use the System roxy as Sverissimo. But still i was getting the same error. So i Disabled the SSL Certificate Verification
Which is in File => Settings => General Tab(Under Request section SSL Certificate verification)

as i was just Learning API through by creating a sample project(API).

Comment: Didn't solve my issue - still getting `ECONNREFUSED`.

Answer (score 1):

I just change http to https, it works. Postman by default set host started as http instead of https.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I resolved it by changing the authorization to no auth and it worked for me
[image]

Comment: Didn't solve my issue - still getting `ECONNREFUSED`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your function dependencies for func.exe to wake up and start listening the endpoints. In my case, functions host was not waking up as it was waiting Cosmos DB emulator.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I changed the port to 8800 port which is what Postman was already trusting for another server. (Before that, I shutdown what I call 'another server' had been working on 8800). And I re-run my app and saw that it worked. Then I changed the port to previous port (the port in which Postman have produced ECONNREFUSED error previously). Finally it worked at that port.

Answer (score 0):

just increase the time for Request timeout

File => Settings => General >Request timeout
more then 1000

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35134594)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while working on **localhost** with port **8000**. I simply went to File -> settings -> proxy and unchecked **use system proxy**. After that I checked **use custom proxy configuration** and I unchecked **https**, checked **http**, filled the port (in my case **8000**). Everything work fine after that

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had my API configured for using HTTPS in the project setup, but the SSL binding was not enabled in the IIS web site. Further information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis#iis-manager) about how to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a Similar Problem on postman

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5001
```

here's a [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxO7a.png) of my error.

so .. if non of these answers worked for you take a look at this:

here's my lauchsettings.json file

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000;https://localhost:5001",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
  }
}
```

instead of using

```
> dotnet watch
```

in terminal i used

```
> dotnet run
```

and it worked!

[vs code terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8u383.png)

( i still don't understand the reason this didn't work and THAT worked but i'm still looking.. also if you have any idea why it worked let me know :D )

hope that was helpful.

UPDATE:

try

```
> dotnet watch --no-hot-reload
```