# node.js Error: connect ECONNREFUSED; response from localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js

I created a node.js app which interacts with MSQL database installed locally, when I ran the app through CMD ( npm start ) api returns the desired results. When I tested through the Postman, it gives Error: connect ECONNREFUSED. Below are the snip of the api code:

```
const db = require('./dboperations');
var Product = require('./products');

var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use('/api',router);

router.use((request,response,next)=>{
    console.log('midleware');
    next();
})

router.route('/products').get((request,response)=>{
    db.getProducts().then(result =>{
    response.json(result);
    console.log(result);
})
})

app.listen(8090, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 8090!');
   });
   
/*
db.getProducts().then(result =>{
    //response.json(result[0]);
    console.log(result);
})*/
```

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60795033/connect-econnrefused-in-postman

Comment: Unfortunately not working.

Comment: **Q1**: How does the postman request look like? (For example: Is the port "*8090*" explicitly named in the URL?) -> Please add this detail to the question.

 **Q2**: Is your app running while you perform the postman request?

Comment: Man!! 2 days an I figured out that the app is not running during performing postman request! Thanks a lot for the hint!

Comment: I have another question, I'm trying to host the app and the sql DB on azure Virtual machine, how can I do the postman request ( to which IP ?) because I tried to call both public and private IP of the VM but it gives connection time out

Answer (score 0):

check your url and config in postman